# Is there a way to export the results of a WMI query using wbemtest?

Tags: wmi

Give this query,

```
Select * from Win32_GroupUser Where GroupComponent <> "Win32_Group.Domain='domain',Name='AnswerGroup'"
```

can I export the results **using wbemtest**? If not, I can create a script that will do it, but I was curious if I could do it directly from wbemtest.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No i don't think `Wbemtest` provides any such functionality. You can use:

```
Export-Clixml
Export-csv
```